# How to sum column based on value in another column in two dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a limit order book and in one of the functions I want to return a list that sums the column 'size' for the ask dataframe and the bid dataframe in the limit order book.

The output should be...

```
$ask
  oid price size
8   a   105  100
7   o   104  292
6   r   102  194
5   k    99   71
4   q    98  166
3   m    98   88
2   j    97  132
1   n    96  375

$bid
  oid price size
1   b    95  100
2   l    95   29
3   p    94   87
4   s    91  102

Total volume: 318 1418
```

Where the input is...

```
oid,side,price,size
a,S,105,100
b,B,95,100
```

I have a function `book.total_volumes <- function(book, path) { ... }` that should return total volumes.

I tried to use aggregate but struggled with the fact that it is both ask and bid in the limit order book.

I appreciate any help, I am clearly a complete beginner. Only hear to learn :)

If there is anything more I can add to this question so is more clear feel free to leave a comment!

Comment: Can you show the input example

Comment: I believe this should be solved by simple operations. However, I'm not sure I follow your problem. Can you explain the input a little bit more? You're inputting "a" and "S" for "oid" and "side", is that it? But how are those related with the output frame?

Comment: @eduardokapp S is the sell side B is the bid side. Oid is the order id. Apologies, should've explained the data in the question. In regards to total volume, oid and price is not relevant. What we need is to calculate the total volume (size) for the sell side and bid side each

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want the sum of the two "size" columns in both dataframes, is that it?

Comment: @eduardokapp yes, i think it is simple but i can't for the life of me do anything without getting the output of "argument is of length zero". i am so bad at R

Comment: Ok. I'm just struggling to understand your function. If your inputs are "book" and "path", how are they related to calculating the sum of the "size" column? I mean, is there some sort of filtering or subsetting that depends on "book" and "path"?